# Searching for users in Foursquare API- Missing credentials error 401

Tags: python, api, foursquare

Please help. I am trying to search for a specific user in Foursquare but for some reason I got  Missing credentials error 401.

```
user_id = '484542633' # user ID with most agree counts and complete profile

url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/{}?client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}'.format(user_id, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, VERSION) # define URL

# send GET request
results = requests.get(url).json()
user_data = results['response']['user']

# display features associated with user
user_data.keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

As documentation [states](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/users/details#authentication), this endpoint is meant to be accessed *on behalf* of the user:

> This endpoint requires user authentication.
>
> User calls require a valid OAuth access token in the query string of each request instead of the Client ID and Secret (&oauth_token=XXXX).
>
> For more information about this authentication method and how to obtain an access token, see the Authentication docs.

This means `v2/users` can **only** be accessed by your app, **after** a user (which can be you, using your own Foursquare account) goes through the OAuth login flow and **grants necessary permissions**. OAuth doesn't mean your app "logs in" as the user, rather that *the user* has given you permission to do *something* on their behalf.

To learn more about OAuth you can watch this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996OiexHze0

To read more about Foursquare's API visit their documentation site: [https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/users/details#authentication)